# Como imprimir todas as vogais presente em cadeia de caracteres?

Tags: python

Estou a aprender agora a programar, e escolhi o Python, e não estou a conseguir resolver este exercicio escolar. O código que tenho é:

```
nome = input("Digite o nome: ")
b = nome.find("a")
```

Este código acha `15` para `nome` igual a "um dois três quatro quatorze", mas queria achar todas as letras `a` e suas posições.

Comment: Não entendi. Qual sua dúvida?

Comment: estou a aprender agora a programar, e escolhi o python e nao estou a conseguir resolver este exercicio escolar

Comment: Mas você tem algum código pronto, começado? Aqui o site não serve para a gente escrever o código pra você. Aqui você fez uma pergunta sobre, por exemplo, Python, e respondemos. Vou editar sua pergunta para te ajudar.

Comment: muitissimo obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### str.find

A ideia que você utilizou está bem próxima da solução final, o principal problema é que o método `find` da *string* retorna apenas o índice da primeira ocorrência da letra buscada.

> **str.find(sub[, start[, end]])**
>
> Return the lowest index in the string where substring *sub* is found within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments *start* and *end* are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if *sub* is not found.

Para encontrar todas as ocorrências, poderíamos utilizar o parâmetro `start`, que define onde começará a análise dentro da *string*. Se definirmos este valor como sendo a primeira posição da letra, o método retornará a posição da segunda ocorrência.

```
nome = input("Digite o nome: ")

start = 0

while True:
    index = nome.find("a", start)
    
    if index == -1:
        break
    
    print("Letra 'a' encontrada na posição %d" % index)
    start = index+1
```

Para uma entrada igual à `batata`, a saída seria:

```
Letra 'a' encontrada na posição 1
Letra 'a' encontrada na posição 3
Letra 'a' encontrada na posição 5
```

Pois nas posições 1, 3 e 5 há a letra "a".

Se desejarmos fazer o mesmo processo para as outras vogais, teríamos que repetir o código. Ainda, esta maneira diferencia as letras "a" e "A", portanto, para o nome Anderson, a letra "a" não seria encontrada.

### loop

Outro método bastante simples, de fácil compreensão para iniciantes, é iterar sobre a *string* através de um *loop* e verificar se a letra é uma vogal. Por exemplo:

```
nome = input("Digite o nome: ")

for index, letra in enumerate(nome):
    if letra == 'a' or \
       letra == 'e' or \
       letra == 'i' or \
       letra == 'u':
        
        print("Encontrado a letra '%c' na posição %d" % (letra, index))
```

Para o nome `batata` a saída será:

```
Encontrado a letra 'a' na posição 1
Encontrado a letra 'a' na posição 3
Encontrado a letra 'a' na posição 5
```

Este método ainda pode ser otimizado para:

```
nome = input("Digite o nome: ")

for index, letra in enumerate(nome):
    if letra in "aeiou":
        print("Encontrado a letra '%c' na posição %d" % (letra, index))
```

Desta forma seria mais fácil contornar o problema de letras minúsculas ou maiúsculas, pois bastaria fazer:

```
nome = input("Digite o nome: ")

for index, letra in enumerate(nome):
    if letra in "aeiouAEIOU":
        print("Encontrado a letra '%c' na posição %d" % (letra, index))
```

Que o programa funcionaria para qualquer vogal, tanto minúscula quanto maiúscula.

### re.findall

Já uma solução um pouco mais avançada é utilizando expressões regulares. Python possui uma biblioteca nativa chamada `re` para tal, possuindo uma função chamada `findall`, que retorna a lista de todas as ocorrências de um padrão em uma *string*. Por exemplo, o seguinte código:

```
import re

nome = input("Digite o nome: ")

print(re.findall(r"[aeiou]", nome, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Retorna a lista de todas as vogais encontradas no nome. Para `batata`, seria retornado `['a', 'a', 'a']`, referente aos três "a" presentes na palavra.

Comment: muito obrigado, superou a minha dificuldade e ensinou-me

Answer (score -3):

Olá, sei que o tópico é antigo, mas acredito que customizei o código.

```
lista = list(input("Digite Texto: "))

for v in lista:
  if v.lower() in 'aeiou':
    x = lista.index(v)
    print("A vogal: " + str(v) + " está na posição " + str(x))
```